# CasperJS gives Syntax Error when using Javascript's test method

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to write a simple function to test whether a value is an integer or not in a CasperJS script however it keeps giving me Syntax Error. The function in question is the following:

```
function isInteger(possibleInteger) {
    var intMatchPattern = new RegExp("/^[\d]+$/");
    return intMatchPattern.test(possibleInteger)​;
}
```

I see nothing wrong with this function however CasperJS refuses to work until I remove the line with ".test" on it.

Is this a known CasperJS bug (Currently using the latest 1.1.0-DEV)? Or maybe a PhantomJS bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an invisible character before the last semicolon.

You can spot this character if you copy/paste your code, for example, in vim or if you tell your editor to show hidden characters.

If you remove this character your code should run fine[image].

I found it out because pasting your code in Chrome javascript console I got the same error as in PhantomJS, rewriting your code by hand I didn't get any error.

Comment: Wow would you look at that. Strangely enough I dont see the character even when copying from my own code above however a rewrite seems to have done the job. Thank you.